# Move Animation within the Timeline

Tags: animation, keyframes

I have an object which follows a 3D NurbsPath.
My object is visible at frame 1 and also my animation starts at frame 1.

How can I "move" the animation, such that my object start getting animated at e.g. frame 30?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. **Moving a Keyframe animation in time:**
   You can move the entire animation sequence from within the Dope Sheet Editor. There you select all keyframes (type "a" on the keyboard once or twice), then for example: <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>30</kbd>  to shift the animation by 30 frames:

   [image: You find the keyframes in the The dopesheet Editor]
2. **Moving a Constrained Path Animation in time:**
   This animation type starts at timeframe 0 by default. Within the Constraints panel you can define an Offset to shift the start of the animation:

   - Open The Object Constraints of the animated Object
   - Set the Offset to the start timeframe where the Path Animation shall begin (30 in this case)

   [image: Set the Animation Offset for a Path Animation]
3. **Moving the Animation time of an Object parented to a Path**

   This animation type starts at timeframe 0 by default and runs for 100 Frames, then it stops. You can define the animation window by setting 2 keyframes in the Path Animation Panel of the Path:

   - Select the Path
   - In the Data Properties locate the Path Animation panel
   - In the Timeline select the startframe for the animation (30 in this case)
   - In the Path Animation panel set the Evaluation time to 0.00
   - Then keyframe the Evaluation time.
   - In the timeline select the Endframe for the Animation
   - In the Path Panel set the Evaluation time to 100 (or to whatever value you have set the Frames Attribute right above the Evaluation tmie attribute)
   - Keyframe the Evaluation time again.

   [image]

Comment: great! I'll try that in a moment! 
Thanks for telling me that the name is "Dope Sheet Editor", because I'll need to do some research on that first.

Comment: i don't see any keyframes. my animation is playing because I'm using a path, but I don't see any keyframes in that Dope Sheet Editor. Am I doing anything wrong?
I see "Dope Sheet Summary" > "NurbsPath" > "NurbsPath.001" > "Evaluation Time"

Comment: if you use a Path Constraint on your object, you will have to set the Timeframe Offset in the Constraint. In that case no keyframes are created.

Comment: still don't see it.
use the default cube. shift+a > add a nurbpath. Extrude the Nurbpath to make it longer. Select both cube and nurbpath and do ctrl+p.  now this is my current situation for my animation. I can't seem to find a path constraint or timeframe offset. The only thing I see is "Frames" and "Evaluation Time" in the Path Animation when I select my nurbspath.

Comment: Now i think i have documented all possible options :) I believe your case is topic 3 in my answer

Comment: I have edited your Original Question for easier finding. I suspect it is worth to split the question into 2 and split the answers accrodingly.

Comment: there should be more people like you giving such detailed answers! +1
For step 3: this video helped also: http://youtu.be/OgF7wTv6a10?t=3m48s

Comment: Maaaan, I've gotta say, I just created an StackExchange account, JUST, to thank you my friend very much!
OOOO my god, I was dying thinking that it would be SOOOOO complicated to make an animation happen after another in a GOD(avoiding many bad words here) animation software.
Spend the hole day looking for a solution, at least I found one! Thanks^^